# Combinatorics Binomial

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

A talk show host has just brought 10 new jokes. Each night he tells some of the jokes. What is the largest number of nights on which you can tune in so that you never hear on one night at least all the jokes you heard on one of the other nights? (Thus, for instance, it is acceptable that you hear jokes 1, 2, and 3 on one night, jokes 3 and 4 on another, and jokes 1, 2, and 4 on a third. It is not acceptable that you hear jokes 1 and 2 on one night and joke 2 on another night.)

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if I would tune in to a talkshow host who buys his jokes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take $n = 3$ first. This gives us the following poset:

[image: Poset of subsets of {1,2,3}]

A set of subsets for which none is a subset of any other is called an *antichain* and you can see that the largest antichain in this poset (a.k.a the width of the poset) is $3$.

For larger $n$, the same picture gives an antichain of length
$$ {n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor} $$
at the middle (the sets of size $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$) and suggests that it is maximal.

In fact, [Sperner proved this in 1928](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem). Sperner's theorem for $n = 10$ gives a maximum of $10$ choose $5$ nights for a total of $252$.